# How do I parse RDD in Scala

Tags: scala, rdd

I have this RDD:

```
Array[(String, String)] = Array((http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOptimizing.html,{(https://www.google.com/accounts/Login?continue=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fwebtoolkit%2Fdoc%2Flatest%2FDevGuideOptimizing.html&amp;followup=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fwebtoolkit%2Fdoc%2Flatest%2FDevGuideOptimizing.html)}))
```

In the value part, the values are of this form: `{}` or `{(value1)}` or `{(value1), (value2), (value3)}`.

I am not able to figure out how to parse these values and make a list of them and then map it to the key.

Because `{}` is not a Array or List.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a data of type `RDD[Array[(String, String)]]` then you can do

```
rdd.map(x => x.flatMap(y => y._1.replaceAll("[{()}]", "").split(",") ++ y._2.replaceAll("[{()}]", "").split(",")))
```

to get

```
RDD[Array[String]]
```

where each of the `(String, String)` *tuples* are separated and collected in an `Array[String]`

**Updated**

Your comment below says

> > The data type is org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] and not RDD[Array[(String, String)]]

So for that case, *inner map of array* can be neglected and you can do as below

```
rdd.map(x => x._1.replaceAll("[{()}]", "").split(",") ++ x._2.replaceAll("[{()}]", "").split(","))
```

You should get the same result as above.

Comment: The data type is `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)]` and not `RDD[Array[(String, String)]]`